# Why can't I view traffic on other devices using WireShark

Tags: encryption, wireshark, tcp, packet-sniffers

I'm running WireShark on the latest version of Ubuntu and I can't seem to be able to capture traffic coming from other devices besides my own. I see a TON of SSDP packets but not much of anything else. Also, I notice that a lot of the packets seem to be encrypted because they have mostly characters that don't mean anything in them. I am positive that I have Promiscuous Mode turned on. Can anyone help with this? I just would like to see decrypted traffic on other devices (my Nexus tablet in particular).

Edit: I can see IP addresses of other devices, however I can't see any TCP packets for them. Only SSDP

Comment: Maybe your upstream switch simply isn't sending that traffic out in your direction...

Answer (score 2):

If this is on a wired network, [it might be switched](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet).

If this is on a wireless network, [you might have to capture in monitor mode](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN).

In both of those cases, promiscuous mode won't be sufficient.